# Remove duplicated code from a Python function that gets data from and endpoint and, after manipulating it, returns the manipulated version

Tags: python, python-3.x, array

I have written the following function for a CLI tool, it works as expected but it also contains duplicated code.

```
def populate_teams_tab(self):
    teams = self.get_data(self.TEAMS_URL)
    returned_list = []
    for team in teams:
        if self.IS_ROGUE:
            if team['id'].upper() == "ROGUE":
                # Here I have a few lines of manipulation that are adding all
                # the ROGUE teams to a list that will be returned
                # I will simplify those steps for clarity using the following line
                returned_list.append(team)
        else:
            # Here I have the _same_ lines of manipulation that are adding all
            # the teams to a list that will be returned
            # I will simplify those steps for clarity using the following line
            returned_list.append(team)
        return returned_list
```

Is adding another helper function the best idea or maybe is there a more elegant solution to get rid of the duplicated part?

Comment: What does this code accomplish? The function doesn't return anything! See [ask].

Comment: I've added the precisation.

Comment: But what does this function do? What class does it appear in?

Comment: Sorry but I do not understand how this can be useful for the question or for future readers.
Putting +100 more lines of code will not add any value to the question and just increase the complexity without a real advantage.
The problem is not repeating code that is basicaly data wrangling.
Adding it wouldn't change the question in any way.
I also already received the answer I was looking for.

Comment: At the least, fix the title to conform to the [ask] guidelines.

Comment: That's not any better. So many of the questions here want refactoring or to eliminate if statements, it's not useful to the site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We don't have the lines of codes you say they are doing the "same" thing. So I should guess.

If those lines of codes have the same logic, just with different data, It's a great idea to separate those lines of codes in another method.

But it seems that those lines just need teams data, not the data that belong to the object. If that is the case, you should separate those lines in a `static` method, in python words, you need to add `@staticmethod` at the top of that method before `def` keyword and you should remove `self` from parameters.

But it is always a great idea to export the same codes in a separate reusable place.